# Filter and gain node influence analyser node

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm using an audio HTML element as an source for web audio context source (createMediaElementSource), then give it to an analyser node, then give it to a gain node, then to series of biquad filter nodes (with different frequencies) and finally to audio context destination. I'm using this for both a visualizer (using analyser node) and a equalizer for music player.

But my problem is changing the filters node gain, gain node and even the audio element volume will change my analyser node's output (getByteFrequencyData). But the analyser node is at the begining and the gain/filter nodes are after it, so changing them should not influence analyser node. Is it normal behavior of web audio API?

P.S: The influence of audio element volume seems OK. It change the source element signal so I think it's normal.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense if the audio graph is arranged as you describe.  Please provide a small snippet to demonstrate the problem.